# Queries on IQueryable with property name and type at runtime

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, expression, azure-cosmosdb

I need to do queries with knowing the property name and type at runtime. I've used reflection on `IEnumerable<>` but will there be issues with performance because of this?

I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this with `IQueryable<>`?
I've looked a bit into `Expressions` but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

**Edit:**

At the moment it doesn't seem to be a performance issue, but I haven't tested yet with very big workloads.

I need to search in multiple fields of different types known at runtime.

```
var cosmosClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(cosmosDBEndpointUrl), cosmosDBAuthorizationKey);
var feedOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };
var objects = cosmosClient.CreateDocumentQuery<MyObject>(collectionLink, feedOptions).AsEnumerable();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchQuery))
{         
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<MyObject>(); 

    foreach (var fieldToSearch in fieldsToSearch)
    {
      predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.GetPropertyValue(fieldToSearch).CheckDateTime().ToString()
                                     .Contains(searchQuery, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
      objects = objects.Where(predicate);
    }
}

objects = objects.Skip(index)
                 .Take(pageSize);

return objects.ToList();
```

And this helper method:

```
public static object GetPropertyValue(this object obj, string propertyName)
{
    foreach (var part in propertyName.Split('.'))
    {
        if (obj == null) { return null; }

        Type type = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty(part, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (info == null) { return null; }

        obj = info.GetValue(obj, null);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I don't know in this particular case if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: Reflection is going to be slower as you are evaluating code at runtime instead of compiling it ahead of time. The performance hit may be worth it depending on your use case.

1) Are you running into any performance issues with your current code?
2) What is the specific problem you are trying to solve? Some contextual information and the code you are working on will make it much easier to try and help you.

Comment: I've added some details and code @SamaraSoucy-MSFT

Comment: Trying not to be too literal, but what do you mean by "I've used reflection on `IEnumerable<>`"? Since Linq functions are extension methods, they aren't tied directly to the interface at all. If you mean you've done reflection on the `Enumerable` static class, you should be able to do something very similar on `Queryable` since the signatures are the same (with the difference that `Queryable` uses expressions while `Enumerable` uses delegates more directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in this case [I do think you want](https://medium.com/@mohamedabdeen/iqueryable-vs-ienumerable-in-net-92a15a803da3) `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable`. The easiest way to remember is that `IEnumerable` loads all the data into memory and then runs the rest of your LINQ query while `IQueryable` tries to run your filters on the source if it can then loads the resulting data into memory. You do need to be using an ORM that supports `IQueryable` like LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework. In the case of CosmosDB, the SDK is built on top of LINQ to SQL.

By using `IEnumerable` you are loading *all* the data from Cosmos into memory and then applying your filters and pagination. It's fine while you only have a few records, but as your dataset grows you can probably imagine how this can become a major problem. Generally you want to do as much work as possible in the database and only return a minimal number of results. That is going to far outweigh any performance considerations from using reflection to build your predicates.

One of the best parts of `IQueryable` is that it inherits from `IEnumerable` so anything that works with `IEnumerable` will work with `IQueryable`. All you should need to do is get rid of your `AsEnumerable()`.

---

It is important to note that not all LINQ operators are automatically supported, and as soon as the system hits one it can't translate it executes what it has so far and does the rest in memory. There is a [list of available operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-linq-to-sql) for CosmosDB in the documentation.

For your query, the big one is going to be that, while your `Where()` clause is supported, `Skip()` and `Take()` currently aren't. That means that each time this method is executed all the results will be returned from CosmosDB and then the pagination will be evaluated.

There are a couple ways to deal with pagination in the SDK. The currently supported way is to set the `MaxItemCount` inside your `FeedOptions` to your page size. Instead of the `Skip()` function, the current system uses continuation tokens. In order to access the token you can use [`AsDocumentQuery()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.linq.documentqueryable.asdocumentquery?view=azure-dotnet). Since you have to step through each page to the next one, caching the tokens can be very helpful- jumping around is tough.

The second option is to use v3 of the .Net SDK. It is currently in preview, but [available on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos). A few months ago [skip/take was enabled](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/pull/249). In that case, everything up until you call `ToList()` should be translated to SQL and evaluated within CosmosDB.